# Sonar issue - Switch cases should end with an unconditional "break" statement

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

I would like to ask you for your help with sonar issue. Sonar marked case EQUALS in the code below as sonar issue squid:S128.

-Switch cases should end with an unconditional "break" statement.
I dont think that in this case I have to add "break" statement.
Can someone help me? Is it false positive issue?

Thank you in advance.

```
  public boolean causeException(Throwable throwable) {
        Throwable causeException = ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(throwable);
       Map<String, MatchMode> configuration = infoMessage.get(causeException.getClass());
            String message = throwable.getMessage();
            for (String key : configuration.keySet()) {
                MatchMode matchMode = configuration.get(key);
                switch (matchMode) {
                    case EQUALS:
                        if (message.equals(key)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    case CONTAINS:
                        if (message.contains(key)) {
                            return false;
                        }
                }
            }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going to get fallthrough if you message doesn't equal key.  You need to add breaks to address this issue:

```
  public boolean causeException(Throwable throwable) {
        Throwable causeException = ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(throwable);
       Map<String, MatchMode> configuration = infoMessage.get(causeException.getClass());
            String message = throwable.getMessage();
            for (String key : configuration.keySet()) {
                MatchMode matchMode = configuration.get(key);
                switch (matchMode) {
                    case EQUALS:
                        if (message.equals(key)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        break; // stops fallthrough
                        // With no "break" it would do the CONTAINS block as well
                    case CONTAINS:
                        if (message.contains(key)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        break; // stops fallthrough
                    default:
                        // just for clarity
                        break;
                }
            }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.